# How to convert date formate from 1999-05-18 to 18 may in uitable view swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsdateformatter

I have url of having dob's list with names and the response comes in this scenario "1993-03-28"....... along names and I have to show the date as 28 Mar I have created array of months and working but It printing all same dates for all members my code is

```
 var  dob = "\(arrdata[indexPath.section].dob)"

    print(dob)
    var dobSplit = dob.split(separator:"-")
    print (dobSplit)
    var mont = dobSplit[1]
    var dat = dobSplit[2]
    print(dat,mont)


    var monthArray = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]
    print(monthArray)
    print(monthArray[Int(mont)!-1])

    var mo = monthArray[Int(mont)!-1]

    var finalDOB = dat + " " + mo
    print(finalDOB)


 // cell.dateLbl.text = "\(arrdata[indexPath.row+1].dob)"
    // instead of that I gave like this 
     cell.dateLbl.text = finalDOB
```

for all names its displaying same dates

EX: Rohit 28 Mar
    Rahul 28 Mar
    Sohit 28 Mar
    Kuldeep 28 Mar

Comment: can you show the sample response or else can you print the print(dob)

Comment: Use `DateFormatter`. Much simpler.

Comment: And shouldn't your data access be based on the row, not the section?

Comment: Reopened because the question isn't about date formatting. That's not the issue.

Comment: You are doing a lot of printing, at what line do you first get incorrect values printed? Is it already at the first print, `print(dob`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`DateFormatter`** to get the required date format like,

```
func getFormattedDate(from str: String) -> String? {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: str) {
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM"
        return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    }
    return nil
}
```

To add the `formattedDate` in your `cell`, use **`indexPath.row`** instead of `indexPath.section`, i.e.

```
let dob = "\(arrdata[indexPath.row].dob)"
cell.dateLbl.text = getFormattedDate(from: dob)
```

Still if it is printing the same date in every `cell` of `tableView`, try adding the `array` of `string dates` that you're using for each `cell`. Also the `UITableViewDataSource` methods.

Comment: You should add a locale (`en_US_POSIX`) at least to get the proper month abbreviations and it's recommended for fixed date formats anyway.

Comment: @vadian This is a case where you don't want that special locale. That's only needed when parsing a string to a `Date` and when that string has English month names and/or it has time. This has neither.

Comment: @rmaddy The explicit `monthArray` indicates that the OP wants English month names and the string **is** parsed to `Date` first. Without the locale you get the month names in the current locale.

Comment: @vadian 1. The explicit month names could mean the OP isn't aware that that isn't a good idea. It's not proof that they only want English month names for all users. But, then again, maybe they do. 2. In reality, you only get month names in the user's preferred language if the app is localized to that language.

Comment: @PGDev Thanks its working the reason why I kept section means I have another view in that I have to show only first response of table view .

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. Change:

```
var  dob = "\(arrdata[indexPath.section].dob)"
```

to:

```
var  dob = "\(arrdata[indexPath.row].dob)"
```

Besides that, use a `DateFormatter` to convert your date string from one format to another. At a minimum, don't hardcode your own month strings. It doesn't localize well. Use `Calendar shortMonthNames` if you don't want to do it properly with `DateFormatter`.